# DotNetNuke 05.06.00 (459) failing with "The AppDomain shut down because of a change to the application level configuration" message

Tags: dotnetnuke, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke-5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've developed a DNN5 site for customer locally on my laptop and I am having problem moving it to a production server. Server is running Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5). I've copied all the files, copied db, modified web.config to see the new db, checked to make sure dnn can see the db via connection string, made sure the directory permissions are correct (appdomain user has RW access to whole virtual directory) .. and it's failing me with following error message taken out of the portals/_default/logs directory:

```
<log LogGUID="a3f8aab9-36b6-4d95-a605-53b4b0b02c34" LogFileID="" LogTypeKey="APPLICATION_SHUTTING_DOWN" LogUserID="-1" LogUserName="" LogPortalID="-1" LogPortalName="" LogCreateDate="2/4/2011 11:52:57 AM" LogCreateDateNum="0" BypassBuffering="True" LogServerName="SERVER01" LogConfigID="">
    <LogProperties>
        <LogProperty>
            <PropertyName>Shutdown Details</PropertyName>
            <PropertyValue>The AppDomain shut down because of a change to the application level configuration.</PropertyValue>
        </LogProperty>
    </LogProperties>
</log>
```

I've been stuck on this for the last 3h .. so any hint's or advice is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Filip

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in the EventLog table?  I don't think that the log file there is going to be an accurate place to get all of your error messages.  In particular, this isn't even an error, just a notification that a few days ago your application was restarted because of a change to the web.config file.

There may be multiple events logged at the same time, so try to take a look at the LogCreateDate attribute, and see if there are other events logged around the same time that might give more information.

Does the process running the website have access to the web.config?  Can you double/triple-check, since it seems like the web.config file is being touched every time you try to hit the website?  Could an upgrade routine be trying to update that on first run of the site?

Comment: This notification is written to log file immediately (!) after DNN return the "This site is currently Unavailable" message back to my browser.

BTW - I've checked EventLog - no error messages there.